# Can you perform hypothesis testing on mutual information values?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mutual-information

I am working on a project that uses mutual information to determine how much information is shared between two "variables" x and y in two separate populations. Essentially, I have two groups and calculated a mutual information value indicating the degree of the relationship between x and y for 10 subjects per group (so 10 MI values in group 1 and 10 MI values in group 2). Can mutual information values be averaged (average MI group 1 vs average MI group 2) and then used in hypothesis testing ( i.e., t-tests, anovas, etc) or are they more like correlation coefficients, or neither?

Comment: How is MI being estimated? Do you have access to the raw data?

Comment: We are using this estimation method: Kraskov, A., Stögbauer, H., Grassberger, P., 2004. Estimating mutual information.
Phys. Rev. E, Stat. Nonlinear Soft Matter Phys. 69 (6 Pt 2). http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15244698. and yes we do have access to the raw data.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about **correlation coefficients**. You can do hypothesis testing on correlation coefficients as well, if you really need to.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that but it requires the use of a different type of statistical test. You don't use a t-test to do hypothesis testing on a correlation coefficient. I'm asking what the appropriate test would be for something like an MI value.

Comment: Ancient question, but I thought you may see [this paper](https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/16/5/2839) -- Exact Test of Independence Using Mutual Information, Shawn D. Pethel, Daniel W. Hahs -- which describes a test of independence using mutual information. I'm not sure if it's implemented in any commonly used software libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Permutation testing seems like a viable option.

You have $n_0$ vectors $Y_{0,1},\dots,Y_{0, n_0}$ in group $0$ and $n_1$ vectors $Y_{1,1},\dots,Y_{1, n_1}$. Calculate the mutual information in each group, and then calculate the difference.

Next, permute the group labels, and calculate the difference in mutual information between permuted group $0$ and permuted group $1$.

Do it again.

Do it again.

Do it again.

Now that you've done it many times, you have a distribution of mutual information differences under the null hypothesis of the groups having the same mutual information within them. That is, the difference in mutual information is zero (which is not the same as saying that the mutual information within each group is zero).

The original difference in mutual information is the test statistic, and we have a distribution under the null hypothesis. Now we can calculate a p-value!